# UILabel null when execute from delegate method

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uilabel

I have controller:

```
@interface BallsViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end

@implementation BallsViewController
@synthesize viewBoard;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle];
    if (self)
    {
      //  ScoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 300, 30)];
      //  [self.view addSubview:ScoreLabel];
        // add other stuff you need to initialize ...
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init
{
    // since we don't wanna re-implement allocation and instantiation for every
    // initializer, we call the 'designated initializer' with some default values,
    // in this case the default nibName and bundle are nil.
    return [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.viewBoard Draw:@"Fields"];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.label.text = @"lll";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)NewGame:(id)sender {
        self.label.text = @"aaa";
    self.viewBoard.canDrawBall = true;
    [self.viewBoard Draw:@"Fields"];
   // }
   // else
   // {
   //     self.InfoLabel.text = @"End game";
   // }


  }

-(void)UpdateScore:(int)score
{
    NSLog(@"%@", self.label);
    NSString *scoreStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
    [self.label setText:scoreStr];

}

@end
```

When I check label in viewDidLoad and NewGame method control is initialized and I can set new value for label.
But when I invoke delegate method UpdateScore, my label is null, even I execute this method after invoke method above I mention.
Why It is happen? How can solve this problem ?

Comment: when is UpdateScore: called? is it from an IBAction?

Comment: By any chance, can `label` be removed from the super view between calling of these two methods?

Comment: What happens if you change it to strong instead of weak?

Comment: You say "delegate" method.  Who is calling `updateScore`, and where did they get the "delegate" pointer??  (I suspect you're creating a new instance of your class as the delegate and it has no nib attached.  This is reenforced by the presence of that bogus second `init` method.  You should never init a VC without a nib.)  (If you copied that from somewhere I'd suggest you ditch that source and find someone else to crib from.)

Comment: @uchuugaka change to strong not solve problem.

Comment: @atreat UpdateScore is call from UIView. I create in this UIView instance of controller and call UpdateScore. Controller have property of this class. When I init in this UIView my label using initWithFrame and addSubView, I can set text to label, but addSubView create additional label, but I create drag&drop this label in designer so this not solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
1> Either you can Do it using XIB or you make it Custom Label
 2> if you want to use XIB then , Drag and Drop UILabel in your XIB, and set its Delegate and LabelName to its property. Now you can set value of label any where in .m file.

3> if you make it CUSTOM , then you will have to write following code in your .m file:
```

- (void)viewDidLoad

UILabel *UrLabel = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width / 2), 0.0, 150.0, 43.0) ];

[self addSubview:UrLabel];

UrLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", score];

Comment: this code create additional label on UI. I add label using designer so I dont want to additional :/